# Dapper sql too slow when in parameter is list string

Tags: c#, dapper

I use raw SQL with parameters in Dapper. Query speed is normal.

Something like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE messages IN ('Volvo', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mazda')"
var results = conn.Query(sql);
```

When I change parameters with `@messages`, the speed is too slow:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE messages IN (@cars)"
string[] cars = { "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" };
var results = conn.Query(sql, new {cars});
```

PS: `string[]` size is almost 300.

Comment: Are you saying you tested this with a query with all 300 values hard coded into the SQL vs the parameter approach?

Comment: i thought you had to name the anonymous fields in the object to match like this string[] cars2 = {"Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda"};
var results = conn.Query(sql, new {cars = cars2});

Comment: The query is executed by the server, not Dapper. Its performance depends on whether `messages` is indexed or not.

Comment: maybe you can trace the executed query and check for the plan to determine what is different ?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 In this case the anonymous object will use the variable name for the property name so if it matches the sql parameter name you don't have to explicitly set it.

Comment: `string[] size is almost 300.` did you try with a raw string with 300 items? It's not possible to pass an array of values as a parameter, so Dapper will actually generate an `IN` clause with the values. The two queries should be identical.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually I believe Dapper will create a query with 300 sql parameters vs the other query that has the values hard coded in the query.  So there might be some overhead from using parameters but I doubt it would be noticeable.

Comment: @juharr in that case, the server won't be able to calculate statistics for the values. If `sometable` is too small, the server may decide to use a scan instead of a seek, especially since it needs to retrieve all columns. BTW without the table schema and row counts, we're as blind as the server.

Comment: How many rows are in `SomeTable` and how many of them would be returned?

Comment: Where did those 300 "cars" come from? If they are the result of some query, could you add that query as JOIN or subselect?

Comment: Are you sure you need the parentheses in `IN (@cars)`? I had to rewrite that to `IN @cars` querying Sqlite - apparently Dapper adds the `( )`

Comment: Apples and Oranges as shown. Add all 300 to your first query then report back.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass string as parameter, Dapper treats it as `nvarchar` type.
So if your `messages` is `varchar` type and the `SomeTable` is huge, even if it's indexed, the speed could be really slow. `DbString` may solve this problem.

```
cars.ToList().Select(x => new DbString { Value = x, IsFixedLength = false, IsAnsi = true });
```

Comment: For list-type values, Dapper rewrites the query

Comment: hi, any pseudo code about how to solve the problem raised by the author? @HansKeﬆing

Answer (score 1):

(would be a mess as a comment)
(I think there might be some syntax error in second one and there shouldn't be parentheses.)

The two queries would generate different SQL sent to backend. ie: with MS SQL server they would look like:

First one:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE messages IN ('Volvo', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Mazda')
```

Second one:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE messages IN (@cars1, @cars2, @cars3, @cars4)',
N'@cars1 nvarchar(4000),@cars2 nvarchar(4000),@cars3 nvarchar(4000),@cars4 nvarchar(4000)',
@cars1=N'Volvo',@cars2=N'BMW',@cars3=N'Ford',@cars4=N'Mazda'
```

IMHO there are better ways of doing IN queries depending on your backend.

Comment: The real difference is that in the first query, the query optimizer can calculate statistics from the values, as they're part of the query itself. In the second, the values are unknown, only their number is known. This is little better than eg a TVP where even the count is unknown

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes and it is a difference. I wouldn't do a parametric in query like this (it could be translated to EXISTS, INNER JOIN ...). Actually in one real world scenario for MS SQL server, I ended creating a CLR function. With over 20K parameters it returned the result under a second against apprx. 500K rows.